# Copying a compressed file line by line

Tags: compression

I'm copying data from ETX to local desktop, but I can only copy about 150 words one time.

I have written a python script using pyautogui package to do the copy/paste for me. But still I want to limit the file size.

So here's what I want to do:

1. I want to compress a file.
2. add newlines and some flags between the file to each line 150 words max
3. copy the file from ETX to local machine
4. remove the newlines and separator
5. decompress the file.

Is this possible? Which compression tool can I use so that it supports copying and pasting?